# Is it halal to use condom?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, family-planning

**Generally,**

Is it halal (allowed) to use condom or any other things like copper-T to prevent pregnancy between married couples?

**Consider the following situation:**

If a women has two children (both are caesarean), and her doctor asked her to set up a family plan, since it will be danger for her health if she has another pregnancy.
But the couple refuses to do that. In this situation, is it halal to use condom/copper-T to avoid pregnancy?

Comment: in general this is allowed as long as there is consent between both spouses... in case of medical/health reasons it is obligatory to take measures (like condom or similar) that reduce the the risk!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So it's ok under the following conditions:

1. Does not harm any partner
2. Both partners agree to it. Each of them has the right to:

   - get a chance of conception
   - get the pleasure

There's an old [Fatwa](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/1219/condoms) of Sheikh Munajjid, I quote as:

> Praise be to Allaah.
>
> It is permissible to use condoms so long as this does not cause any
>   harm and so long as both husband and wife consent to their use,
>   because this is similar to ‘azl (coitus interruptus or “withdrawal”).
>   But it reduces the sensation of pleasure, which is the right of both
>   partners, and reduces the chance of conception, which is also the
>   right of both partners. Neither one of them is allowed to deprive the
>   other of these rights. (For more information, see Question #1100 and
>   566). And Allaah is the Source of strength.
>
> Islam Q&A Sheikh Muhammed
>   Salih Al-Munajjid

Comment: So what about couples which wife agrees and husband disagrees? And what about the HIV risk?

Comment: Then they should agree on another solution :). I don't know about HIV in marriage!

Comment: There is no should in real life and no body can force humans to do something which may harm them. HIV is one of disease that can transfer by sexual relationships between a person (male or female) who is a positive HIV and a person (male or female) who is a negative HIV and may no one of them knows about it. Does it seem such weird to ask it? They can have it before marriage or be polluted by non sexual ways like taking blood in a hospital or anything else which can pollute their blood.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Thanks Allah, HIV is not popular in Egypt where I live. JAK ;)

Comment: @TarekEldeeb I don't think HIV is *popular* anywhere :)

Comment: if someone is worried about their partner being positive in HIV, then I assure them it's not easily possible to be protected against that if you will be continually having intercourse with them. It's not one or two days, it's years and decades, so better choose the right person to marry than think about protecting yourself from HIV coming from that person.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is allowed only with respectful reasons like you said.

i think maybe another proper behaviour in the example you told is abstinence and fasting.

i think there can be physical exercises to make child born without cesarean section.

about general usage of condoms without respectful reasons i think:

changing what is made by allah is prohibited in quran 4:119.

israf is prohibited in several ayats (17:26, 6:141, 7:31, 26:151, 39:53).

a hadith about coitus interruptus : http://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/182 : muhammad said: It is better for you not to do so ...