# Is family planning permissible in Islam?

Tags: sharia, family, birth-control, family-planning

I am really concerned about what is going on in my country which is family planning to avoid children. Is it allowed in Islam because I believe what Allah has ordained for us will surely happen and I believe that we shouldn't hesitate to follow what Allah has enjoined us to do. I am from Nigeria.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the kind of family planning ?

Comment: That they don't want to bear More than 2 two child then they planned for it and if allah had said they will bear 7 child?

Comment: I meant more specific about the family planning techniques (like here for instance http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7846/is-it-halal-to-use-condom ). Or are you asking if married people should try to have as many children as physically possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which country is it? It would help to check the laws made in their original form.

Answer (score -4):

no it is generally forbidden 
but in rare cases where life of mother is in danger then it is permitted

Comment: Please add evidences to support your claims on the whole this looks more like a comment not as an answer as we expect here (read [answer]).