# What does Islam say about the right of the wife to have a child?

Tags: sex, husband-wife, pregnancy

I have been married for over one year and I desire to have a child but my husband is not "mentally ready" to have children.  I have tried convincing him, reasoning with him, talking to him so many times but he always says no not yet.  Me and my husband both pray and try to follow Islam the best we can.  I even tried to reference the Quran  and tell him that God is the one that provides for us and a  that a child is a gift.

After several attempts, I am left with no choice but to completely deny using protection when we are having sex.

Is it wrong in Islam to request your husband to not wear a condom when having sexual intercourse?  What does Islam say about the right of the wife to have a child or the right of a husband to give his wife a child?  Will I be punished by God for not allowing my husband to have sex with me without a condom on?

Comment: The ruling of most sunni schools  is that contraception can **not** be used by the husband without the wife's consent, the exception being the Shafis, who attach dislike to contraception. See [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38428/20218) related question.

Answer (score -3):

In Islam it is prohibited for a woman to have a  child if not married and if married it is acceptable for the man to refuse children until They are in better living economic standard of supporting the child

Comment: This guy is spamming. Someone should ban him