# Can a non-Muslim wife swallow her husband's semen?

Tags: sex, non-muslim, husband-wife

I know you can't do anal sex or oral sex, but can my non-Muslim wife swallow semen/male fluids if she is allowed to?

And are there different limits?

Answer (score 1):

limits with Muslim wife or non Muslim wife is the same what is allowed to do with your Muslim wife you can do with your non-Muslim wife it's your wife .
and for wife swallow semen there is no Explicit statement in Islam about it,
 people prefer not to swallow it because it's like mucus it's tahir (Pure, clean) but disgusting it's preferable and advisable to not to do

Comment: AFAIK the problem with swollowing semen is rather that it is not the explicit purpose, as it should be used for fertilization not to be "thrown or spit away".

Comment: this is different things,there is no problem in thrown or spit away the sperm because in prophet's time( صلى الله عليه وسلم ) It was proven from the Sahabah (may Allah be pleased with them) that they were isolated.
If the need for isolation to shed his penis outside the vagina either because he does not want to pregnancy at that time or she is in Menstrual cycle.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Wouldn't the pull-out method be haram too then? But that's allowed by explicit hadith if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @G.Bach that method was allowed with slave girls only, for doing so with the wife one needs her permission, I think the hadith is clear about this point!

Comment: @Medi1Saif [Seems like that's a matter of madhab](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38428/17702), I didn't know - I can't find a hadith specifying consent of the wife as mandatory.

Comment: "AFAIK the problem with swollowing semen is rather that it is not the explicit purpose, as it should be used for fertilization not to be "thrown or spit away" @Medi1Saif what if someone has a sterile wife, or had her ovaries removed because of cancer. Does that mean he will need to divorce her? or keep her as a wife but refrain from having sex with her, as there is no point in doing that, since fertilization is not going to take place...

Comment: @QaisarKhan the comment was on the explanation given in the answer, it is not covering all cases. Allah told us that we may have children and we might not have. In the case of a wife that isn't able to give birth it is still her right to have intercourse and satisfaction too.

Comment: @G.Bach as said before the hadith quoted in the answer actually quotes slave-girls!

Comment: "it is still her right to have intercourse and satisfaction too" @Medi1Saif Then it doesn't matter if she consumes semen via mouth or the vagina. If swallowing is what gives her pleasure and satisfaction, let's us not act as control freaks by prohibiting her from her basic right.