# I am pregnant with the third child and as per the doctor we cannot have more than three child after C section

Tags: hadith, sunnah, imaan

So as per the researcher the doctor say that we need to have only three child through C section after that it is risky to have the baby so this is my third time I am having my baby and it could be C section so how should I prevent that I should have not have baby  in future as it's my effect my health can I go for some options for not having baby will it be accepted in Islam.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it permissible to use contraception during intercourse?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38380/is-it-permissible-to-use-contraception-during-intercourse)

Comment: Certainly there's nothing wrong with that if husband and wife agree they can stay without even having children. Further your husband would commit a sin if he urges you to avoid contraception in future since it would be harmful to you.Be aware that after a C-section you can't give birth normally anymore as per what I've learned. And also even a second birth by C-section is already somewhat critical. So you might consider seeking advice on how you may reduce any health issues in future.

Answer (score 0):

If the preventation method is not permanent there is no problem.

> Rule 1: In general, it is permissible to use birth control to prevent
> pregnancy, and it is (also) permitted to use the (various) forms of
> birth control.
>
> Rule 2: If becoming pregnant would lead to a danger or hazard to the
> woman’s life, then the woman is permitted – for as long as there is a
> probability of her life being in danger – to employ the methods of
> birth control and it does not make any difference if the danger (to
> her life) is immediate or if it would come about later on.
>
> Rule 3: The religiously approved methods which one may make use of to
> prevent pregnancy include:
>
> a) Birth control by using devices such as an I.U.D. (Intrauterine
> Device), condoms or the injection of a drug (to prevent pregnancy) and
> other things such as these.
>
> b) Natural methods of birth control: This would include Coitus
> Interruptus or ejaculating outside of the wife. However if this method
> of birth control leads to other forms of physical or mental illness
> for the woman and man, then it would not be permissible.
>
> c) Conditional Birth Control: What is mean by this is that at the time
> of reciting the marriage contract, the woman makes a condition that
> for a certain period of time or for as long as they are married, she
> would use birth control and her husband also accepts this condition.
>
> Rule 4: It is permissible to have one’s tubes tied (Tubal Ligation -
> Tubectomy) to prevent pregnancy as long as this procedure is temporary
> (reversible) and would not lead to a woman being permanently unable to
> conceive nor would this act cause any sort of life-threatening
> conditions. In addition, once the tubes have been re-opened, she would
> once again have the ability to conceive. In other than this scenario,
> it would not be permissible to perform the Tubectomy.
>
> Rule 5: The ruling on having one’s tubes tied (Tubectomy or Vasectomy)
> is the same for both men and women (as has been mentioned above).
>
> Rule 6: In using any of the methods of birth control that are
> available, it is essential for the woman to have the consent of her
> husband and the wife is not permitted to go forth and use any of the
> methods without first taking the approval of her husband.
>
> It is permitted to employ birth control methods, keeping in mind the
> following three conditions:
>
> 1. The procedure does not damage the (sexual) organ nor would it lead
>    to permanent sterilization.
> 2. The husband approves of the use of birth control. 3) The procedures
>    that would be employed for birth control and placing the device
>    related to it (inside the person) would not involve the performance of
>    a forbidden (haram) act.
>
> Controlling the number of children and regulating ones’ family can be
> examined from two different aspects:
>
> 1. The steps which are employed before conception (birth control).
> 2. The steps which are employed after conception (abortion).
>
> According to the fatwa of the late Imam Khumayni (may Allah be pleased
> with him), the first method (of birth control) is permissible as long
> as no forbidden acts are performed in order to achieve it.
>
> As for the second method (abortion), it is forbidden (haram) except if
> necessity expedites that it be done however this act must be performed
> before the soul is infused into the fetus – meaning before the fetus
> has reached to the age of four months – in which case it is
> permissible.
>
> *** The Noble Prophet (blessings of Allah be upon him and his progeny) has said: “The best of you is the person who acts in the best way with
> his family and I am the best of you in relation to my family.”
>
> Wasa`il ash-Shi`a, Volume 14, Page 122, Hadith 8

[Reference](https://www.al-islam.org/islamic-edicts-family-planning/birth-control)

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on your pregnancy! It's important to prioritize your health and follow the advice of your doctor regarding the number of children you can have after a C-section. Islam encourages Muslims to take care of their health and make informed decisions regarding their well-being.

In Islam, family planning is allowed and considered permissible within certain boundaries. It is recommended to consult with knowledgeable scholars or trusted medical professionals who can provide guidance specific to your situation. They can help you understand the options available to you and provide advice based on Islamic principles and medical expertise.

Remember that Allah is the Most Merciful and All-Wise, and He understands the unique circumstances and challenges we face. It is important to seek His guidance through prayer and supplication, and make decisions that are in the best interest of your health, the well-being of your family, and in accordance with Islamic teachings.

May Allah bless you with a healthy pregnancy, a safe delivery, and a happy and harmonious family.

There is no specific limit mentioned in the Qur'an or Hadith regarding the number of children a couple can have.

However, it is important to prioritize the health and well-being of both the mother and the child. If your doctor has advised against having more children after a C-section, it is essential to follow their medical advice. Islam encourages us to take care of our bodies and seek medical guidance when needed.

In the Qur'an, Allah says in Surah Al-Baqarah (2:195): "And do not throw yourselves into destruction." This verse emphasizes the importance of taking care of oneself and avoiding actions that may harm our well-being.

Additionally, the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said in a Hadith narrated by Abu Hurairah: "Your body has rights over you." This Hadith highlights the importance of taking care of our bodies and not putting ourselves in harm's way.

Therefore, it is recommended to consult with your doctor and make decisions regarding family planning based on their professional advice, taking into consideration the well-being of both the mother and the child. May Allah bless you with a healthy pregnancy and a safe delivery.